# Suppose three fair dice are rolled. What is the probability at most one six appears?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, dice

From Ross, Intro to Probability Models - Chapter 2.

10. Suppose three fair dice are rolled. What is the probability at most one six appears?

**Attempted Solution**

The total amount of combinations are 216. Find all combinations with at most 1 six:

These will be 6 _ _ -> 25 combinations, _ 6 _ -> 25 combinations. and _ _ 6, which are another set of combinations. These give me 75 combinations. Then, there are the set of combinations where there is not a 6. These can be found by:

$$P(No \space 6s) = \binom{3}{0}(\frac{1}{6})^0(\frac{5}{6})^3 = \frac{125}{216}$$

So then the total probability becomes 200/216.

We can get the same solution by taking the approach from behind: find all cases where there is at least 2 or 3 sixes and subtract from 1:

$$1-\operatorname{nCr}\left(3,2\right)\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^{2}\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)-\frac{1}{6}^{3}$$

Why is the Ross solution 198/216? Can someone help me out?

Comment: I also got $\;\frac{200}{216}\;$ ...but I usually suck at combinatorics and probability.

Comment: Your answer of $\displaystyle \frac{200}{216}$ is correct, and can be alternatively computed by noting that of the $216$ rolls, there is exactly $1$ way of getting all $3$ 6's and exactly $15$ ways of getting exactly $2$ 6's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer is correct, and the second method is how I would have done it. It appears that there is an error with the book. I wrote a simple python program that checks all possibilities and count when there is $\leq 1$ six (just cause I wanted to confirm I wasn't screwing up my math)

```
count = 0
for i in range(1,7):
    for j in range(1,7):
        for k in range(1,7):
            if ((i==6) + (j==6) + (k==6)) <= 1:
                count += 1
print(count)
# Output is 200
```

Since there are $200$ cases of at most $1$ six, then the probability is $\frac{200}{216}$

Comment: Thanks, the edition of the book is a little old (1972) which may explain some of the errors. I'll make a note in my page.